# Akka.NET .NET Framework - Akka.Remote config always errors on start (then works fine)

Tags: c#, .net, akka.net

I am trying to configure a remote Actor, but I am having some trouble.
Every time I start up my console app, I am greeted with an error:

(I cannot catch it for some reason, but here is all the information I can gather from it):

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
   at Akka.Actor.ActorPath.ToStringWithAddress(Address address) in D:\a\1\s\src\core\Akka\Actor\ActorPath.cs:line 738
   
   System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Akka
  StackTrace:
   at Akka.Actor.ActorPath.ToStringWithAddress(Address address) in D:\a\1\s\src\core\Akka\Actor\ActorPath.cs:line 738
```

From what the error says it looks like I am not configuring an address. In all my research on how to configure akka remote actors I have not found a way to configure an address.

Here is my code:

```
        using Akka.Actor
        using Akka.Configuration

        var config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(@"
        akka {  
            actor {
                provider = remote
            }
            remote {
                dot-netty.tcp {
                    transport-protocol = tcp
                    port = 8091
                    hostname = ""127.0.0.1""
                }
            log-remote-lifecycle-events = INFO
            }
        }");

        using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("MyServer", config))
        {
            system.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new AkkaCalcServerPipeTo()), "CalcServer");

            ...
        }
```

Is there a way to configure Remote Actors to remove this error?
My assumption is my configuration is so wrong that I am getting this random error.

I am running on the .NET Framework 4.7.2 if that helps.

EDIT:

I've realized this may not be enough information, I have added the `AkkaCalcServerPipeTo` class below in case that helps:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Akka.Actor;
using CalcMessages;

public class AkkaCalcServerPipeTo : ReceiveActor, ILogReceive
{
    public AkkaCalcServerPipeTo()
    {
        Receive<Messages.AdditionRequest>(ar =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received addition request {0} + {1} - {2}", ar.A, ar.B, DateTime.Now);
            Sender.Tell(new Messages.CalcResponse(ar.A + ar.B), Self);
        });

        Receive<Messages.SubtractionRequest>(sr =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received subtraction request {0} - {1} - {2}", sr.A, sr.B, DateTime.Now);
            Sender.Tell(new Messages.CalcResponse(sr.A - sr.B), Self);
        });

        Receive<Messages.MultiplicationRequest>(mr =>
        {
            var self = Self; // closure
            Task.Run(async () => {
                await Task.Delay(2500);//Thread.Sleep(10000);//
                Console.WriteLine("Received multiplication request {0} * {1} - {2}", mr.A, mr.B, DateTime.Now);
                mr.Sender.Tell(new Messages.CalcResponse(mr.A * mr.B), self);
            }).ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (x.IsFaulted)
                {

                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).PipeTo(self);

        });

        Receive<Messages.DivisionRequest>(dr =>
        {
            var self = Self; // closure
            Task.Run(async () => {
                    await Task.Delay(10000);//Thread.Sleep(10000);//
                    Console.WriteLine("Received division request {0} / {1} - {2}", dr.A, dr.B, DateTime.Now);
                    dr.Sender.Tell(new Messages.CalcResponse(dr.A / dr.B), self);
                }).PipeTo(self);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this 100% of the code that causes this error to be thrown? Or is it something that your `AkkaCalcServerPipeTo` actor is doing?

Comment: @Aaronontheweb This is the code causing the error - the error triggers right on the `using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("MyServer", config))` line

Comment: @Aaronontheweb I added the `AkkaServerPipeTo` class as well for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue.
The post is old, but somehow I receive the same error during the start.
If I remove the part where I configure the remote information in the config-file no error occur.

I upgraded to the latest version.